# Is there a way to convert an annotated dataframe into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert an annotated DataFrame into a regular pandas DataFrame. I tried using anndata.AnnData.to_df but it says my DataFrame has no attribute 'AnnData.' Is there something else I should try or is my syntax incorrect?

[My code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfc0o.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Embed your example code in the post and do not link to it as an image, as the latter makes it difficult for someone to reproduce your steps. A basic question now. What is `AnnData`? Your code does not contain an import of an appropriate package.

Answer (score 0):

@alexis sample input data would be better to reproduce the error , although i replicated your scenario with below sample data. But before proceeding ahead please make sure to install "pip install anndata".

```
#sample csv input data
# Gene,Samples1,Samples2,Samples3
# Gene1,1,2,3
# Gene2,4,5,6
# Gene3,7,8,9
# Gene4,10,11,12

import pandas as pd
from anndata import AnnData

df=pd.DataFrame({"Gene":['Gene1','Gene2','Gene3','Gene4'],"Samples1":[1,4,7,10],"Samples2":[2,5,8,11],"Samples3":[3,6,9,12]})
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)


counts = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

counts = counts.set_index('Gene')

counts = counts.T

counts = counts.drop_duplicates()

counts_adata = AnnData(counts)
print(counts_adata)
print(counts_adata.X)
print(counts_adata.obs_names)
print(counts_adata.var_names)

counts_df = counts_adata.to_df()

print(counts_df)
```

output

```
AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 3 × 4
[[ 1  4  7 10]
 [ 2  5  8 11]
 [ 3  6  9 12]]
Index(['Samples1', 'Samples2', 'Samples3'], dtype='object')
Index(['Gene1', 'Gene2', 'Gene3', 'Gene4'], dtype='object', name='Gene')
Gene      Gene1  Gene2  Gene3  Gene4
Samples1      1      4      7     10
Samples2      2      5      8     11
Samples3      3      6      9     12
```

Comment: I already installed anndata via pip. I tried your method but still got the same error:
UserWarning: Variable names are not unique. To make them unique, call `.var_names_make_unique`.
  utils.warn_names_duplicates("var")